# Javascript: Converting URL containing JSON into traversable variable?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

Javascript: If I have a url that has contents that are just in JSON, how do I go from the url to having the JSON stored in a variable that I can traverse and get certain values from?

For example the url might contain something like this and nothing else:

```
{"cookies": [ {"chocolate": 50}, {"raisin": 12} ]  }
```

How might I extract the contents of the URL to have the object that I can assign the contents to a variable, say x, and then use functions like x.cookies to get   [ {"chocolate": 50}, {"raisin": 12} ]  }??

Thanks so much! I greatly appreciate your help :) Have a great day!

Comment: Do you mean you want to parse a JSON string into a JSON object? `JSON.parse(urlString)`

Comment: Are you asking how to fetch the url?

Comment: yeah @ray. I need to fetch the url!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), or if you're using jQuery you can use [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: This would work wonderfully but JSON.parse takes a string. I need to give it a url from which it will extract the string contained on that site and then I can parse it. In other words, if you know how to go from a URL and converting the contents o that url to text, that would be what I need. I think Python has the ability to import urllib which can read URLs but is there an equivalent in Javascript?

Comment: Updated my answer with links on how to fetch a url.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse is the general command to convert a JSON string to a variable.

```
var x = JSON.parse('{"cookies": [ {"chocolate": 50}, {"raisin": 12} ]  }');
console.log(x.cookies);
```

Comment: This would work wonderfully but JSON.parse takes a string. I need to give it a url from which it will extract the string contained on that site and then I can parse it. In other words, if you know how to go from a URL and converting the contents o that url to text, that would be what I need.

Comment: Oh, so you'd want to use an AJAX library like JQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Something like
`
$.ajax({
  url: "http://path-to-content",
})
  .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR  ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Server returned:", data);
    }
  });
`

JQuery will automatically parse the JSON text to an object